# What is the proper way to disable daylight savings auto-adjustment on WinCE?

Tags: windows-ce, dst

I want to programatically uncheck the "automatically adjust the clock for daylight savings" check box from a compact framework application running in WinCE.

Google searches indicate that you can do this in Windows by setting the DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet value under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation key.  This key doesn't appear to exist in WinCE.  Is there a different way to do this in WinCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer I can find on this is to use the "HomeDST" registry key:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202749.aspx

There is an "AUTODst" registry key also which seems to automatically adjust, but that appears to depend on SNTP.  If anyone knows a way to automatically adjust for DST in WinCE without using SNTP please comment.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable DST with this command `tzutil /s Pacific Standard Time_dstoff`.